# basic question about coregraphics

Tags: ios, core-graphics

Im working on a project with out Interface Builder,

i want to draw a line and a test square, but is not working
here the code

> ```
> - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
>  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
> CGContextClearRect(context, rect);
>  //Set the stroke (pen) color
> CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
> //Set the width of the pen mark
> CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5.0);
>   //Start at this point
> //CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 10.0, 30.0);
> CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 20, 20);
>   //Give instructions to the CGContext
> //(move "pen" around the screen)
> CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 310.0, 30.0);
> CGContextStrokePath(context);
>  // Draw a red solid square
> CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 255, 0, 0, 1);
> CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50));
>  }
>  - (void)viewDidLoad
>  {
> [super viewDidLoad];
>  self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
> self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
>    UILabel *labelA = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 20)]autorelease];
>       labelA.text = @"mk ss9";
> [self.view addSubview:labelA]; 
> }
> ```

the label shows fine, but the line and square are not showing, what is missing??

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok got it!

the problem is that I was attempting to draw in my ViewController, and that is not the way,

So I created a new class, with subclass UIView, and it works fine now!